# Can we hide the caret in a number field without disabling it

Tags: jquery, html

I have a **spinner** - not a text field or a textarea

`<input type="number" />`

[image]

It would be nice to not have the blinking caret in the field when the control is clicked.

[image]

The answer to [How to hide the caret in an HTML text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333919/how-to-hide-the-caret-in-an-html-text-input-field)

does of course not work since the spinner does not run when the field is disabled or readonly.

Neither does [Hide textfield blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor) which is not a spinner

Also [jQuery UI spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) has the same issue

Comment: Under what conditions do you want the carat (cursor?) not to blink?

Comment: When the control is focussed.

Comment: I think you have to put up with it. For `type="number"`, focus/spinner/blink all come as a package. You could try `type="text"` with `pattern="[0-9]*"` but I think you will get the same issue.

Comment: I want the spinner so type=text is not an option

Comment: It's somewhat cumbersome but you could try the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor).

Comment: No I cannot. I need a spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blink is part of the native input representation - you'd have to hack it to A) make said input invisible and B) reproduce its content elsewhere.

A) I'd suggest using `colour: transparent`. If older browser support (I know old IEs won't like this) you can go for `visibility: hidden` or other techniques, but then addressing focus will be tough.

B) Create a wrapper around the input with `position: relative`, then a span immediately afterwards that will match the input value whenever it changes.

Here's a simple codepen example:

http://codepen.io/barneycarroll/pen/beFgm

Comment: It should be now — are you sure Javascript's enabled?

Answer (score 1):

`css:`

```
.your-field{
    color: transparent;
}
```

1. add wrapper to the field with `position: relative;` and a `span/div/whatever` after the field with `position: absolute`.
2. position span correctly (it's top-left should overlap with input text start position)
3. add event handler on `keyup/keydown/custom arrow click/any event that changes input val`
4. handler function (jQuery):

   ```
   function() { $('.your-absolute-positioned-element').text( $('.your-field').val() ); }
   ```

Comment: Thanks - I went with the complete example by Barney.